# Incorrect `event.target.value` in `onChange` handler of Redux Form `Field` for checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Testing the following piece of code with Redux Form 7.4.0:

```
<Field
  name="employed"
  id="employed"
  component="input"
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

What seems strange to me is that when I click the checkbox for the first time I can see that `e.target.value` is an emty string. When I click the checkbox for the second time `e.target.value` is `true` but I can see that the checkbox is *unchecked*. When I click I click the checkbox for the third time `e.target.value` is `false` but I can see that the checkbox is *checked*. This behavior seems to me incorrect end different from behavior of

```
<Field
  name="lastName"
  component="input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Last Name"
  onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)}
/>
```

for which `e.target.value` is the same as the current value visible in the input field.
Can someone clarify this different behavior? Is it an issue of React Form?
I'm using Redux Form oficial example for testing https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox value is not like an `input`, the value of the checkbox is inside `e.target.checked`

Comment: Great thanks! `e.target.checked` works exactly as expected. I completely missed this property, my bad.